# Generic function -> Cannot convert return expression to return type

Tags: ios, swift, generic-programming

Here is a little issue I am having using a generic function. Probably a basic error due to a lack of practice with generics. Anyway, below is the code relevant to the question.

The generic function itself, not showing any error:

```
func setThingRevision<GenericType:Revisionable>(entity name: String) -> [(GenericType,Int)] {
    var resultArray = [(GenericType,Int)]()
    // ..... we do some useful magic ......
    return resultArray
}
```

Some code using the generic function above:

```
func setMyRealStuffRevision(entity name: String) -> [(RealType,Int)] {
    return setThingRevision(entity: name)
}
```

Here is the error message given by the compiler in the last function (setMyRealStuffRevision):

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '[(_, Int)]' to return type '[(RealType, Int)]'
```

Rather than being surprised by the message, **I wonder what is the right syntax to use.**

My *RealType* is compatible with *GenericType*, but I am not sure if I need provide some information to the setThingRevision generic function or if it can be inferred from the context.

--- Addition ---

Here is a fake *setThingRevision* that I created for testing purpose.

```
func setThingRevision<GenericType:Revisionable>(entity name: String) -> [(GenericType,Int)] {
    var resultArray = [(GenericType,Int)]()

    // Here name contains the name of a Core Data entity and getArrayFromEntity is
    // a local function, extracting an array from the contents of the entity.
    for item in getArrayFromEntity(name) as! [GenericType] {
        resultArray.append((item, 99))
        return resultArray
    }

    return resultArray
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Let me see if I can make something. What I can already say is RealType is a subclass of NSManagedObject.

Comment: I'm not quite understand what happening because for me (even if RealType is inherited from NSManagedObject) this code is buildable.

Comment: @Paulw11. I edited the post (see after --- Addition ---) Hoping this added code will allow you to test simply. I my case I still get the same error with this testing code.

Comment: It's still not a [mcve] - because it isn't *complete*.  Please try and provide *complete* code than when simply pasted into Xcode produces the error. e.g. What is `revisionKanaArray` ?  Should that be `resultArray`?

Comment: e.g. This https://gist.github.com/paulw11/7a877a412d661f5e6665695bb70e85c2 works and does not show the error that you are seeing; therefore more information is needed.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, it was a mistype, it should be resultArray.

Comment: As already noted repeatedly, what you have shown till now is not sufficient to reproduce your issue. Please show actual `Revisionable` and `RealType`.

Comment: You're right, it's going to take a bit of time making a real demo min., compl. and verif. (though it'd be the best) so I was hoping to find a solution by direct investigation rather than taking the basic (but sure) way. I think I know where my mistake is, your code works but it is not a subclass of NSManagedObject and I think this is where my problem is. My protocol is only trying to require that the NSManagedObject has some predefined properties and it does not work as I expect. I don't know if it sounds clear but I should make a small demo as you said (unless I get lucky quickly).

Comment: What is Revisionable ?

Comment: It's a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

On type safe languages if a "induced" conversion cannot be done, the compiler will tell you that message. Somehow 'var resultArray = (GenericType,Int)' it's not interpreted as a type that can be converted to the type of the return function. Examine closely the type of resultArray assigned by the compiler. The right syntax to use would be not using 'var' to create the resultArray variable, instead, explicitly define the type.

Comment: I am looking into that. Now RealType has exactly all the fields required by the Revisionable protocol, no more no less. But strangely enough I still get the same error.

Comment: Do some test on the side and see if you can typecast realArray to the returning type. I really doubt it but you can try anyway.

Comment: You mean the other way around (returning type to realArray) ? I am trying, but if I want to write something like "let x = setThingRevision(entity: "some-name")". How am I supposed to specify the real type to use for the generic type. What I tried did not work?

Comment: What I'm saying is, instead of returning directly the value of the 'setThingRevision(entity: name)' , do 'var dummy = setThingRevision(entity: name)' and inspect the type returned of dummy. Also, try a typecast conversion of dummy into another variable 'dummy2' of the same typeof the setMyRealStuffRevision func, to see if it can be converted.

Comment: OK. Then I need to know how to do 'var dummy = setThingRevision(entity: name)' because its says it cannot infer the type (which is to be expected) How do I tell setThingRevision what to use for the generic type in that case?

Comment: Is there a way to specify that a parameter p of a generic function needs to be a subclass of class C and support the protocol P.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func setThingRevision<T: Revisionable>(entity name: String) -> [(T, Int)] {
    var resultArray = [(T, Int)]()
    // ..... we do some useful magic ......
    return resultArray
}

func setMyRealStuffRevision(entity name: String) -> [(RealType, Int)] {
    return setThingRevision(entity: name)
}

protocol Revisionable {
}

// edited
class RealType: NSManagedObject, Revisionable  {
}
```

Comment: What is the point except changing GenericType to T? Beside RealType is a subclass of NSManagedObject not a struct.

Comment: T we use as convention, T as Template. GenericType or T your wish.